# how to style writeText Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to style the text in the writeText tag in Javascript.
I am trying to have the words Eyes and Blue on different lines. I also want to have one in a larger font than the other one. How can I target them individually?

```
<head>
    <script>
    function writeText(txt) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <img src ="test.png" alt="Jacket" usemap="#test" />
    <p id="test"></p>
    <map name="test">
        <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350"href=#; title="FInd" alt="Find" onmouseover="writeText('Eyes Blue')" onmouseout="writeText('')"/>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: I'm sorry, but what? Can I (strongly) suggest you take a few moments to read "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make two different tags for those two texts. texts within one tag can only have one style. you can do something like `<p somestyle>text1</p><p somestyle2>text2</p>`

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I would do   
function writeText(txt1) and
function writeText(txt2) ?

Comment: @Rika you can do that in a single function, just assign different id to those two tags

Comment: thats what I was thinking and tried but where do I put the Id's? This is what I tried
<p id="test">
    <map name="test">
        <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350"href=#; title="FInd" alt="Find" onmouseover="writeText('Eyes')" onmouseout="writeText('')"/></p>

<p id="test1">
    <map name="test">
        <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350"href=#; title="FInd" alt="Find" onmouseover="writeText('Blue')" onmouseout="writeText('')"/></p>
But then it only displays the first one.

Comment: @Rika i dont think you can nest another tag inside p tag, as mentioned by Vohuman. Even though some browsers let you do it, its not standard

Comment: Well, I wrote "you can't nest the `p` tags", i.e. `<p><p></p></p>`. But you can use all the [phrasing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories) tags in the `p` tag.